# how do you add to a 2D arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code. I know the star is correct but I can't add to the arraylist

```
private ArrayList<int[]> action = new ArrayList<int[]>();
action.add(new int[2]);
```

then I have

```
action.add({4,8});  // error
```

Why cant I add `{4,8}` to the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write it out in full:

```
action.add(new int[]{4,8});
```

The plain `{...}` short-hand only works when initializing the array at the time of declaration:

```
int[] a = {4,8};  // works

int[] b;
b = {4,8};  // error
```

See [JLS §10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also  do it as following:

```
int[] b = new int[2];
b[0] = 4;
b[1] = 8;
```

Then:

```
action.add(b);
```